# Download GIS data using owslib

Tags: python, anaconda

I want to create a geopandas dataframe from a url using owslib:

```
from owslib.wfs import WebFeatureService
url = 'https://somesecreturl.com/geoserver/wms?&authkey=79sd7a9sd-sda798-4531-a8a9-454hj5h3453' #(I've changed the authkey)  
wfs = WebFeatureService(url=url)
```

Last line is causing error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 2, in 
> wfs = WebFeatureService(url=url)
>
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\owslib\wfs.py",
> line 42, in WebFeatureService
> return wfs100.WebFeatureService_1_0_0(clean_url, version, xml, parse_remote_metadata,
>
> File
> "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\owslib\feature\wfs100.py",
> line 80, in **new**
> obj.**init**(url, version, xml, parse_remote_metadata, timeout,
>
> File
> "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\owslib\feature\wfs100.py",
> line 105, in **init**
> self._capabilities = reader.read(self.url)
>
> File
> "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\owslib\feature\common.py",
> line 53, in read
> request = self.capabilities_url(url)
>
> File
> "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\owslib\feature\common.py",
> line 28, in capabilities_url
> qs = cgi.parse_qsl(service_url.split('?')[1])
>
> AttributeError: module 'cgi' has no attribute 'parse_qsl'

The exact same code is working on Another computer (with other versions of some packages and python)

I have tried to export the working env package version as a text file and:

```
conda create --name <env> --file <this file>
```

But that is giving me:

> Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done Solving
> environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will
> retry with next repodata source. Collecting package metadata
> (repodata.json): done Solving environment: failed
>
> PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from
> current channels:

What can I do now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "solution" was to uninstall Anaconda and install an older version (Anaconda3-2019.03)

then install packages:

- geopandas
- owslib

And update pyproj package